# How to define semantic reasoning path and area on ontologies based on RDF with pellet reasoner?

Tags: rdf, owl, reasoning, pellet, allegrograph

I created a complex ontology that represents a **product structure**. I defined the most rules to describe configuration of the product (if you use Part A1 you can't use Part B1 --> you have to choose Part B2 or Part B3).

Now I create a product by assigning existing Part Instances to it. I want to check if the product is possible to build based on configuration rules.c If a product contains A1 and B1 it is not possible to build.

[image: Product Structure]

Can I configure a reasoner not to check the whole ontology but only recently added products starting from the hierarchically highest product instance? Which reasoner should I choose to be able to do that?

**EDIT**

**Reasoning on the whole data set is costly regarding execution time - can I set a "reasoning range" and starting point to accelerate the process if I know where changes were made?**

I use AllegroGraph and design Ontologies in Protege or TopBraid Composer to export it to AllegroGraph in RDF. TopBraid has a Built-in reasoner (TopSpin).

Thanks!!!

Comment: A standard reasoner works on the whole dataset with the inference mechanism that the reasoner is based on. I don't understand exactly what you want to know. To you want to use a SPARQL query with reasoning? Or what is the purpose of the reasoner?

Comment: @AKSW Please see the EDIT

Comment: @AKSW Maybe we discuss it in a chat room if thats ok?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try **incremental reasonin**g after modification. If you have **Pellet** reasoner installed on **Protege**, you should have this possibility `(Reasoner tab --> Pellet (Incremental))`. This does not recompute everything but rather treats the changes incrementally.

Comment: Protégé is just an editor, my database is AllegroGraph - you are right I can experiment with Protégé but not use is for real data...